How can I use Service Mesh in GCP (formerly Traffic Director) to send requests to Cloud Run?
I have a small client VM that I set up using the steps outline here: https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/service-routing/set-up-envoy-http-mesh
Everything works as expected, I can send a request to a managed instance group and it correctly load balances. So far so good!
What I cannot seem to figure out is how to create a configure the service mesh to send requests to a Cloud Run application.  I have a serverless network group setup, but I cannot figure out the correct combination of backend parameters to correctly add this to the mesh as a new http route
What I've tried
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create hello-green-neg --cloud-run-service hello-green --network-endpoint-type=serverless --zone=us-central1-a
gcloud compute backend-services create hello-blue-backend --global --load-balancing-scheme=INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend hello-blue-backend --network-endpoint-group hello-blue-neg --global --network-endpoint-group-region=us-central1

This gives me
gcloud.compute.backend-services.add-backend) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.backends[0]': '{  "group": "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/blah/regions/us-central1/...'. Invalid load balancing scheme for global backend service with Serverless network endpoint group.


For information, something is cooking ;)

It looks like you are using Global Backend Service and it is for a small client VM, better to use Regional backend service instead of using Global backend service.
As per the official GCP document on Backend services overview :
You can Use Regional External Application Load Balancer, which uses a single serverless NEG (Cloud Run only) as a supported backend type.
Create a Regional backend service in the same region as your serverless NEG with the help of below example command :

gcloud compute backend-services create hello-blue-backend 
--region=us-central1 
--load-balancing-scheme=INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED

After creating Regional Backend Service, add the Cloud Run Serverless NEG to this Regional Backend Service and also adjust your service mesh configuration to point to the Regional Backend service. This may require you to update Envoy proxy configuration.

@JedA, Let me know if the provided information was helpful.If yes,you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . I am happy to assist you in case of any queries.

I tried the above command but got Invalid value for field 'resource.loadBalancingScheme': 'INTERNAL_SELF_MANAGED'. Load balancing scheme for a regional backend service must be one of INTERNAL, INTERNAL_MANAGED, EXTERNAL or EXTERNAL_MANAGED.

Answering my own question here but is seems that the GCP cloud mesh only supports certain backends.
From the documentation found here: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service

Each backend service supports one of the following backend combinations:

All instance group backends: One or more managed, unmanaged, or a combination of managed and unmanaged instance group backends
All zonal NEGs: One or more GCE_VM_IP_PORT or NON_GCP_PRIVATE_IP_PORT type zonal NEGs
One internet NEG of type INTERNET_FQDN_PORT
One or more service bindings


So GCP Traffic Director/Service Mesh doesn't seem to support sending traffic to serverless NEGs
Also to avoid any confusion, here is the correct way to add a serverless NEG to a backend
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create hello-neg --cloud-run-service hello-service --network-endpoint-type=serverless --zone=us-central1-a
gcloud compute backend-services create hello-backend  --global
gcloud compute backend-services add-backend hello-backend --network-endpoint-group=hello-neg --network-endpoint-group-region=us-central1 --global

